# Magento cloud docker environment cannot send out email to mailhog

Tags: magento2, magento-1, docker, cloud-docker

I am using the official cloud docker image to setup local environment
[docker-development](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/docker/docker-development.html)

However it cannot send out email even if  I already put

> environment:
> - ENABLE_SENDMAIL=true

Under fpm container in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

This is due to docker image version incompatibility.

If you are using 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.4-fpm-1.2.4 in your fpm container, you can check the dockerfile is detecting

> ENV ENABLE_SENDMAIL=true

[7.4-fpm-1.2.4](https://hub.docker.com/layers/magento/magento-cloud-docker-php/7.4-fpm-1.2.4/images/sha256-700c0fe7546f2479ebfdb4a842034ceb724b64bde074017ada3982802e285e32?context=explore)

But if you are using 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.4-fpm-1.3.0'

You will see

> ENV SENDMAIL_PATH=/dev/null

[7.4-fpm-1.3.0](https://hub.docker.com/layers/magento/magento-cloud-docker-php/7.4-fpm-1.3.0/images/sha256-c79034d851b72e0d218c353a7af6ad845f186bbbd071a45dd0066cd514c79a80?context=explore)

which are totally different variables.

So the solution is to add a new SENDMAIL_PATH to let fpm container to know which email service should be used. Under docker-compose.yml fpm section, add the following:

```
environment:
      - SENDMAIL_PATH=/usr/local/bin/mhsendmail --smtp-addr="mailhog:1025"
```

Then you can now see your email appear in the :8025 mailhog panel.

Answer (score 1):

@leo solution works, but it´s not persistent. To make it persistent, in the **.docker/** folder, there is a distributable file called **config.php.dist** as a template for the environment configuration. Rename it to config.php and add the sendmail_path configuration there:

```
    'SENDMAIL_PATH' => '/usr/local/bin/mhsendmail --smtp-addr="mailhog:1025"'
```

Execute the ece tool to generate the docker-compose.yml file:  `vendor/bin/ece-docker build:compose`. And you are all set!

Note 1: If you don´t have the distributable file, run `vendor/bin/ece-docker build:dist`. It will generate two files inside **.docker/** folder: **config.env** and **config.php.dist**.